# Azure VNET peering in multiple subscription

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, subscription, azure-virtual-network

I have 8 Azure subscriptions, and I want all VNET in each subscription to communicate with each other and any one of them act as hub for all so that I may apply firewall all in that with the gateway.

All deployment is in same region and same Azure directory.

I have created VNET peering between all VNET as it's implicit so it becomes like mess network now.

Is there any other possible way to do this?

My main motive is that all VNET communicates with each other and same firewall rules over all subscriptions.

Comment: What is `same firewall rules over all subscriptions.`, Do you want all Vnets pass through the same NSG?

Comment: hii @Nancy : yes i do want that...and what security i can add when i connect it to on permices network..

Comment: It depends on the services(like http, rdp) that you want to access, refer to [NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-vnet-plan-design-arm#security).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can consider creating a hub-spoke-hub-spoke topology, where the first level of spokes also acts as hubs. The following diagram shows this approach.

[image]

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke#recommendations).

> The hub VNet, and each spoke VNet, can be implemented in different
>   resource groups, and even different subscriptions, as long as they
>   belong to the same Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant in the
>   same Azure region. A hub-spoke topology can also be used without a
>   gateway, if you don't need connectivity with your on-premises network.

VNet peering connection is non-transitive. If you have multiple spokes which needed to take to each other, you can consider using **UDR**s to force traffic destined to a spoke to be sent to an NVA acting as a router at the hub VNet. This will allow the spokes to connect with each other. Also, you can use UDRs in the spoke to forward traffic to the hub with **allow forwarded traffic** enabled.

Comment: May I know if you need more info in this case or you can accept it if it helps?:)

Comment: hello @nancy
in this case How  'Hub Vnet'  can communicate with 'spoke1 Vnet '
do we need to do peering between them also???

Comment: Yes. peering two. In this case, you do not need to peering between spokes like spoke1 to spoke2.  But Pure VNet peering connection is non-transitive. eg, Vnet A peers with B, B peers with C, A still need to peers with C.

Comment: hello nancy i have all connections, in the mentioned architecture all things are working but like spoke 2 and spoke 3 are not talking with each other. so i make one subscription as hub and peered it with remaining all and also peered other one from each other.

Comment: i am really thakful for your kind support.thankyou so much.....i am new in azure and want to go for 70-533 certification...any advice orpath i may follow...????

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://cloudacademy.com/learning-paths/azure-70-533-certification-exam-prep-43/).